# VNC with localhost, through ssh tunnel using plink.exe

Tags: ssh, putty, vnc, localhost, tunnel

I have a remote computer that I would like to VNC to. This computer can only be accessed through a tunnel. For security reasons, I would like to setup the VNC as a localhost.

On my client PC I run windows. I set up the tunnel with plink.exe. I can connect when setting the VNC without a localhost, using:

```
plink -L localhost:5901:vnc_host:5901 username@tunnel_machine
```

But it fails when starting the VNC to listen on localhost

For clarification, the following won't work, because I don't have a direct access to the vnc_host.

```
plink -L localhost:5901:localhost:5901 username@vnc_host
```

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution using:

```
plink -t -L localhost:5901:localhost:5901 username@tunnel_machine ssh -L 5901:localhost:5901 vnc_host
```

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  It would be helpful to others with a similar problem if you could add a few sentences to explain what this does.